# How to wait until the scheduled task completes execution

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

How to wait until the scheduled task completes execution, before starting the next iteration. The following options all fail to work

```
@Scheduled(cron = "*/30 * * * * *")
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 30000, initialDelay = 1000)
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 30000, initialDelay = 1000)
```

I have a thread pool of 100 for running long running tasks within a single iteration

```
@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfiguration implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(100);
    }   

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());
    }   

}
```

Refer https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html

Comment: `fixedDelay` should work, what do u mean by all failed ?

Comment: What @RyuzakiL said. The [`@Scheduled` docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/integration/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled) states _"... the period is measured from the **completion time** of each preceding invocation...."_

Comment: I am using fixedDelay with 30 seconds interval and the next iteration just starts without waiting for the first one to complete. I modified to Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1) for single thread execution, right now it waits. its not clear to me

Comment: If you want to wait for one task to finish before starting the next task, why do you want 100 threads?

Comment: @k314159 The thread pool size should be irrelevant though. You can use a thread pool if you have multiple long running tasks scheduled, because by default those tasks all share a single thread. However, for a single scheduled task, the delay should work the same regardless of the thread pool size.

Comment: Anyways, I can't reproduce this issue. If I use `@Scheduled` with `fixedDelay` with a simple logging statement and your configuration, I see that the delay works properly. So you may want to share a more complete example, or tell us how you verified that the delay doesn't work.

Comment: Can you sleep for a long time than the delay and check, which is what is happening in my case

Comment: Can't reproduce. I've written a `@Scheduled` method with fixedDelay=1000, which sleeps for 1500 ms, and this method gets correctly invoked every 2500 ms as expected, even though it runs on a different thread each time.